# UWP Публикация в маркет

Tags: uwp, microsoft-store

Написал UWP приложение и пытаюсь опубликовать его в маркете. В следствии чего, получилось следующее:

- Я отправляю пакет на сертификацию и дальнейшую публикацию;
- После публикации (как пишут в дев центре) в маркете, я не могу найти
  свое приложение.

Приложение доступно только по прямой ссылке, а в поиске его не найти. Не совсем понимаю причину такого поведения. Как быть в такой ситуации?

Answer (score 1):

В общем, решение в том, что решения нет.
Получая аккаунт разработчика по DreamSpark (BizSpark), вы можете публиковать свои приложения, но скачивать другие пользователи его смогут только по прямой ссылке. Т.е. в маркете его видно не будет!